# Is falling of the end of a boost::asio::awaitable<void> co routine without a co_return undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, boost, c++20, boost-asio, c++-coroutine

Is falling of the end of a boost::asio::awaitable co routine without a co_return undefined behavior (UB)? I could not find anything to this in the boost documentation. [Cppreference says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines#Execution), its UB when there is no `Promise::return_void()`, in contrast to `promise.return_void()` which it says will also be called, for all cases including `co_return` and falling of the end of the co-routine.

However I found different behavior, one suggesting UB:
[Code on Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/4e3Pd5aK3)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

boost::asio::awaitable<void>  coroutineA() {
    std::cout << "coroutineA" << std::endl;
}

boost::asio::awaitable<void> coroutineB() {
    std::cout << "coroutineB" << std::endl;
    co_return;
}

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context context;

    auto waitA= boost::asio::co_spawn(context, 
      coroutineA(), boost::asio::use_future); //Seems to cause UB
    auto waitB = boost::asio::co_spawn(context, 
      coroutineB(), boost::asio::use_future);

    std::thread t([&context] () {
        context.run();
    });
    waitA.get();
    waitB.get();
    t.join();
}
```

Execution of `coroutineA` leads to a crash with this simple code, in other demo cases it leads to a non 0 program code but non blocking execution.

The only clue I could find was in the boost code: Boost 1.82 `asio/impl/awaitable.hpp` defines `void return_void()` for both `template <typename Executor> class awaitable_frame<void, Executor>` and `template <typename Executor> class awaitable_frame<awaitable_thread_entry_point, Executor>`. The former one should, to my understanding, the promise type we have for both your coroutines.

Cppreference states, both cases `co_return` and falling of the end will call `promise.return_void()`, i.e. `awaitable_frame::return_void()`, which I would argue is defined.

So again, is falling of the end of a boost::asio::awaitable co routine without a co_return undefined behavior (UB)? If yes, why? Could someone point me to the documentation, or better show me the flaw in my reasoning.

Comment: It seems the problem could be that a function is not yet a coroutine for a C++ compiler unless it contains one of the `co_` keywords. If it contains one of the keywords, as `co_await` for example, falling of the end, seems to more or less yield the same code as `co_return` but I am not sure, see : https://compiler-explorer.com/z/je8nv8aej

Comment: MSVC [rejects `coroutineA`](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/v4eMnzjPT).

Comment: @康桓瑋 But adding `co_await` somewhere in the function and MSVC compiles happily https://compiler-explorer.com/z/n6GxneEeo

Comment: I don't think any coroutine stuff is relevant in this example. You basically manually invoke normal function `coroutineA()` ignoring compiler warnings and falling of the end of a non-void function is an UB.

Comment: @user7860670 [C++20 Draft](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4861.pdf) states in 9.5.4 Coroutine definitions [dcl.fct.def.coroutine] subsentence 6: Note: If the unqualified-id return_void is found, flowing off the end
of a coroutine is equivalent to a co_return with no operand. Otherwise, flowing off the end of a coroutine
results in undefined behavior (8.7.4). — end note] https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.coroutine#note-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the C++20 draft and further experimentation I feel confident enough to say:

> Is falling of the end of a boost::asio::awaitable co routine without a co_return undefined behavior (UB)?

### TL;DR

**It depends.** If there is **any** other **coroutine keywor**d in the **function body** like `co_yield`, `co_return` (like in an if branch) or `co_await`, then it's **not UB**. If there is **not at least one co routine keyword** in the function, it **is UB**. This is true for all C++20 coroutines where the used promise defines `return_void()`

### [Example](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/daq7evj1G)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

boost::asio::awaitable<void>  coroutineA(boost::asio::io_context& context) {
    boost::asio::steady_timer t(context);
    t.expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    co_await t.async_wait(boost::asio::use_awaitable);//now this is a coroutine, falling of ok
    std::cout << "coroutineA" << std::endl;
}//only ok thanks to 2 lines above

boost::asio::awaitable<void> coroutineB() {
    if (false) {
        co_return; //Now this is a coroutine, falling of ok
    }
    std::cout << "coroutineB" << std::endl;
}//only ok thanks to 3 lines above

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context context;

    auto waitA= boost::asio::co_spawn(context, 
      coroutineA(context), boost::asio::use_future); 
    auto waitB = boost::asio::co_spawn(context, 
      coroutineB(), boost::asio::use_future);

    std::thread t([&context] () {
        context.run();
    });
    waitA.get();
    waitB.get();
    t.join();
}
```

### Reasoning

The C++20 Standard and later (I uses Draft N4861 and the latest) states in  9.5.4 Coroutine definitions [dcl.fct.def.coroutine] [in 1:](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.coroutine#1)

> A function is a coroutine if its function-body encloses a coroutine-return-statement (8.7.4), an await-expression
> (7.6.2.3), or a yield-expression (7.6.17).

[and in 6](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.coroutine#6)

> The unqualified-ids return_void and return_value are looked up in the scope of the promise type. If both
> are found, the program is ill-formed. [Note: If the unqualified-id return_void is found, flowing off the end
> of a coroutine is equivalent to a co_return with no operand. Otherwise, flowing off the end of a coroutine
> results in undefined behavior (8.7.4). — end note]

So under the assumption that the used promise defines `return_void()` correctly, which e.g. `boost::asio::awaitable<void>` does i.e. in this case, falling of the end of a *coroutine* is fine.

**BUT** it is only a *coroutine* if, and only if (iff), its *function* body contains i.e. "encloses" one of the current 3 coroutine keywords: `co_return`, `co_yield`, `co_await`. It does not matter if they are actually executed. **Otherwise we simply have a *function*, not a *coroutine*, and falling of the end of a non void function is undefined behavior (UB) i.e. really really bad (crashes, works sometime and so on).**

IMHO it seems the C++ committee refrained for some reason to introduce an `async` keyword for function declarations, like JS and Python does. If C++ would have one, this behavior would be not that surprising for C++ programmers I guess.

Comment: I think your "it depends" is misleading – in actual fact, if a function body does not contain any `co_` keywords then it is definitively not a coroutine and so does not relate to the question as asked.

Comment: How is that misleading? When I say exactly that directly after "it depends". Also the question the "it depends" is referring to is asking without a specific co keyword, i.e. co_return. And a function without co_return ca be a coroutine, as by using co_yield or co_await. And in that case the answer to the question would be non UB i.e. NO. In other cases yes i.e. UB.

Comment: The answer to "Is falling of the end of a boost::asio::awaitable<void> co routine without a co_return undefined behavior?" is unequivocally "no". It doesn't 'depend' on anything; rather if what you have isn't a coroutine then the question doesn't apply.

Comment: You might be technically right, but IMHO this detail is not relevant to the SO reader, that reads only the tl;dr part. All they want to know is what to do, to avoid UB. The semantic confusion is part of an organic question, that I came up, when I did not know better. The exact semantics and reasons are still explained in the later part of the answer. Even if they should only copy'n paste the code, the copy the explaining comments. You don't see the benefit to go full language lawyer on a  developer with a short attention span.

Comment: However, @ildjarn I welcome any feedback, especially constructive to my statements of course. But I have a hard time to understand yours: Are you suggesting to modify the question, to proper semantics? Or how would you phrase the tl;dr i.e. what and how would you suggest to change the answer, to improve helpfulness?